# Should this class be in the ServletContext or session scoped in a JSP web applicaiton?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, parse-platform, servletcontextlistener

I am working on a JSP web app to use HttpURLConnection to receive and transfer data from/to a Parse.com database via their REST services. The web application will need to be deployed on Google App Engine or Amazon Web Services.

I have defined a ParseUtils class that is responsible for getting or posting data from or to the Parse database tables through HttpURLConnection class. It has many functions in it and each function establishes a HttpURLConnection for a particular Parse table.

Hope I have given out as many details as needed. My question is: should the ParseUtils class be declared and initialized in the ServletContext when the ServletContext gets initialized or be defined as a session-scoped object for each session? Any best practice?

Thanks!

Comment: Does it contain any session-specific state?

Comment: No it does not. Each function only opens a HttpURLConnection by a URL, reads the input stream, parses the data,  maps the data to data model.

Comment: Then it should go into application scope. (ServletContext)

Comment: What if in case two users log in the app and try to call the REST service at the exactly the same time? Would the application scope object stuck the network traffic or behave abnormally?

Comment: Well, you need to keep that class thread-safe. But you'd also need to do that in session scope (the same user could load two tabs at the same time). Ideally, your ParseUtils has no mutable state at all (after it has been initially constructed with some configuration for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connection objects are typically not "shareable" in the concurrent access sense of the word (they are *reusable* however, in that turn-based access is permissible in a managed environment/execution context). Given that [`HttpURLConnection` is not threadsafe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272681/httpurlconnection-thread-safety), there's no reason to keep it in a global, shared-state component like the `ServletContext`.

That leaves you with the request and session scopes, and also a need to answer the following questions

1. What's the overhead associated with establishing a new `HttpURLConnection` for each request?
2. What's the likelihood/need that a single connected client would need to open two pipes, i.e. two `HttpURLConnection`s in a single session either by way of a new window or tab

The answer to #1 is *the overhead is there, but very slight*; if there's even a slight chance of #2 being a possiblity, you definitely want to open a new `HttpURLConnection` per request, or better yet consider springing for [Apache's HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/) to take advantage of stuff like connection pooling

Comment: Currently ParseUtils gets initialized in the ServletContextListener with only a few configurations. It doesn't keep any state. Each JSP page when loaded calls a function of ParseUtils to open a new HttpURLConnection for a different URL to different Parse.com tables. I don't think there is an overhead associated with establishing a new connection for each request, or it does not matter.

Comment: What I am unsure is what'd happen if a user (session A) is trying to call a function of ParseUtils to post some data while at same time another one is trying to call the same function or different function using another session (session B). Would those requests be queued?

Comment: There's no real disadvantage to going the safe route, i.e. one-connection per session; why not stay safe? @alextc

Answer (score 1):

> What I am unsure is what'd happen if a user (session A) is trying to call a function of ParseUtils to post some data while at same time another one is trying to call the same function or different function using another session (session B). Would those requests be queued?

If ParseUtils does not store any data in its instance variables, you are perfectly safe. Local methods are thread safe and can be invoked concurrently provided it does not use instance variables.

As an analogy, think how a single instance of a Servlet can process multiple requests. The request processing methods (doGet() or doPost()) are local methods of the servlet that are accessed concurrently to serve multiple parallel requests. You are safe as long as you do not have mutable request data stored in instance variables.

Comment: Thanks ramp. The instance variables are only configurations and static variables throughout the application life cycle. So it makes me safe.